# How do I turn off the "suggested news" stories on Chrome's homepage in v70?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Chrome 70 - homepage now showing "suggested news" stories and is sucking up data and is slow. The flags solution is now gone in Chrome 70. How do I get rid of this stupid news feed?

Answer (score 3):

Flags solution works but with a different flag

- `Chrome://flags`
- Disable `enable-ntp-remote-suggestions`

[image]

(Click to enlarge)